# Unable to read environment variable in Nest

Tags: nestjs

```js
const redisModuleFactory = CacheModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    store: redisStore,
    host: configService.get('REDIS_HOST'), // undefined here
    port: configService.get('REDIS_PORT'), // undefined here
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});

@Module({
  imports: [
    redisModuleFactory,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [ConfigService]
})
```

I am unable to read `.env.local` using `configService` inside Redis module above. I keep getting undefined.

Comment: Is the code shared `app.module` or a custom module?

Comment: `ConfigModule` loads `.env` as default, maybe you have to custom this behavior by providing the correct env file path `imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: '.env.local', })],`

Comment: @RobinThomas app.module

Comment: @hoangdv I have already have that but still not working